# Taking data from an adjacent cell by name in cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am a basic Excel user.
I do a monthly rota which has the staff name in one cell and in the following cell it has the hours worked.

Is there a simple way to write an formula so that Excel takes any data from an adjacent cell with a name in and totals it up?

For example:

```
A1 - Mark   B1 - 5
A2 - Jane   B2 - 8
C1 - Mark   C1 - 5
D1 - Jane   D2 - 8
```

This continues with many more names throughout the month. Currently I am starting a cell with a staff name in and the in the adjacent cell doing `=SUM()` and then clicking each cell they work with a plus sign between.

e.g., `A35 - Mark   B35 - =SUM(b1+c1)`

After my last response to another question, I am thinking there must be an easier way as this is very time-consuming and also prone to error.

Comment: Your cell layout doesn't make sense — you have two cells labeled `C1`; you have names in `A1`, `A2`, `C1`, and `D1`; and you have numbers in `B1`, `B2`, `C1`, and `D2`.  Please [edit] the question and fix that.

Comment: Look at the `SUMIF` formula.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty unclear to me, but I think you're looking to calculate sums of hours for names on a list. In that case, you can use [sumif](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)

Say your names are in column A and the hours are in column B - here's your total for "Mark"

```
=SUMIF(A1:A10,"Mark",B1:B10)
```